# Python Telebot API. Не могу прикрутить inline кнопку к картинке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вот логика кода. Бот отправляет картинку в телеграм канал. Хочу прикрутить к этой картинке 2 инлайн кнопки лайк и дизлайк. Бот отрпаляет картинку но инлайн кнопки не появляются

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_rand_photo(message):
  if message.text =='фото':
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    like_button= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Like")
    keyboard.add(like_button)
    dislike_button =types.InlineKeyboardButton (text="Dislike")
    keyboard.add(like_button)
    all_photo_in_directory=os.listdir(PATH)
    random_photo=random.choice (all_photo_in_directory)
    img=open (PATH + '/' +random_photo, 'rb')
    bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id,'upload_photo')
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,img)
    img.close()
```

Comment: Вы в `send_photo` забыли передать `reply_markup=keyboard`

Comment: Если добавляю bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,img, reply_markup=keyboard) то все крушится(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас отсутствует `callback_data` в параметрах для инлайн кнопки.

Код ошибки не предоставлен, но скорее всего она возникает именно из-за этого.
После добавления этих значений(они должны быть разные) так же нужно передать в send_photo `reply_markup=keyboard`, чтобы кнопки вывелись на экран.

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
like_button= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Like", callback_data='like')
keyboard.add(like_button)
dislike_button =types.InlineKeyboardButton (text="Dislike", callback_data='dislike')
keyboard.add(like_button)
bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,img, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Все сработало. Не подскажите , как реализовать что по клику на лайк или дизлайк данные будут собираться где нибудь, например в mysql?

Comment: @AlexNikitin делайте для callback даты условие. `if message.data == 'dislike':` и запись в бд. Должно прокатить, точно не скажу. Лучше попробуйте обратится к [хорошему гайду](https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter8.html)